# barryvdh/laravel-dompdf doesn't work last version for now

Tags: laravel, pdf-generation, dompdf

My code doesn't work. I use Laravel framework. Error on the picture. I think maybe it's looping

config/app:

```
'providers' => [
Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
 ],
 'aliases' => [
 'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
 ],
```

web.php //routes:

```
Route::get('/', function () { //Авторизация
  return view('auth.authorize');
})->name('/');
Route::namespace('App\Http\Controllers')->group(function () { 
  Route::post('/auth', 'AuthController@auth');  
  Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {  
    Route::get('/layouts', function () { 
      return view('layouts.app');
    });
    Route::get('/logout', 'AuthController@logout'); 
    Route::get('/deals/preview/{id}', 'DealsController@preview')->name('deals.preview'); //this
    Route::get('/deals/generate/{id}', 'DealsController@generatePDF')->name('deals.generate'); //this
```

My controller:

```
use PDF;
class DealsController extends Controller
{...
public function generatePDF($id)
    {
        $application_form = Application_form::find($id);
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('deals.show', ['application_form'=>$application_form]);
       return $pdf->download('demo.pdf');       
    }...
}
```

my blade show.blade.php:

```
 <a href="{{ route('deals.generate', ['id' => $application_form->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Generation to pdf
          <i class="fa fa-pencil-square"></i>
        </a>
```

It's my error. Laravel doesn't generate my PHP-HTML page.

[image: It's my error laravel don't generate my php-html page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Maximum execution time error** is related to your PHP configuration, It isn't related to Laravel. Open `php.ini` change the `max_execution_time` to 300 seconds. Like this:

```
max_execution_time = 300
```

The other way is that you can increase the execution time limit only for specific php scripts, by inserting one of the following codes on top of your php file. Like this:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

Or

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: I think problem not there, because I wait one minute. I can't find a problem.

Comment: @Вадик. Do you try this answer? or increase value 300 to more.

Comment: Thank you, it helped. However, the pdf file is generated in 55 seconds. Unfortunately, this will not work in a real project. I used the DomPDF library in another project before, the pdf file was generated instantly. I don't understand why it's so slow